# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined Array.map

Tags: node.js

I am making and API REST and take the data that is important for me. And i want to split the property @type to get the last value in the example "CuentacuentosTiteresMArionetas" of it and i am doing it like this

```
titulos = url.data["@graph"].map(titulo => ({

        titulo: titulo.title,
        tipo: (titulo["@type"]).split('/').pop(),
```

Of the following data

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWStx.png)
It gives me the error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined Array.map.

When I try it apart with a let with that value it works correctly but not in the map

If someone could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply split within a return

```
titulos = url.data["@graph"].map(titulo => ({
  return {
    titulo: titulo.title,
    tipo: (titulo["@type"]).split('/').pop(),
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried like that but it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this and works:

```
titulos = url.data["@graph"].map(titulo => ({
  titulo: titulo.title, 
  tipo: titulo["@type"] ? titulo["@type"].split('/').pop() :null,
})
```